# How to make a fixed card content in css

Tags: html, css, card

I want to make a card, with an image, text and a button. The button in the card should be fixed on the bottom of the card, but my button position is depend on the text. I want my button position is fixed on the bottom of the card no matter how much the text is.

How can I achieve that?

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #345676;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.Track {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.track-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.track-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.album {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 15rem;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.album-image {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.album-image img {
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.album-info {
  padding: 1rem;
  /* background-color: cadetblue; */
}

.album-info h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.album-info h4 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.album-info button {
  background-color: #921233;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.album-info button:hover {
  background-color: #92a113;
}
```

```html
<div class="Track">
  <h1 class="title">Song Playlist</h1>
  <div class="track-list">
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisquam sint dolorum quasi labore dolore inventore voluptatum nostrum adipisci est temporibus iure in, obcaecati neque tenetur tempore nisi sapiente molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisquamiente molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisqadipisci est temporibus iure in, obcaecati neque tenetur tempore nisi sapiente molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum do sapiente molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisquam sint dolorum quasi labore dolore inventore voluptatum molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-meninsky-le1d5k?file=/index.html)

Comment: One method might be to make each card a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) with its [direction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) set to `column`; then align the button item to `flex-end`. It might help to include your code here in your post; please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I'm sorry for not to put my code here. I tried your solution, it's make my button goes down, but also with the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change class button to this and add position relative to class album

```
.button {
     padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
     border: 0;
     border-radius: 0.25rem;
     cursor: pointer;
     background-color: #cccccc;
     box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
 }
 .album {
     position: relative;
     border-radius: 1rem;
     background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
     width: 15rem;
     padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
 }
```

good luck :]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with flex box with flex grow on the ablum and album info components. I also had to add a div surrounding the title and info headers so that I could do space between.

If you use flex-grow, you can avoid setting an exact height and will be responsive if you add more content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #345676;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.Track {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.track-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.track-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.album {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 15rem;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.album-image {
  width: 80%;
  /* margin: auto; */
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.album-image img {
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.album-info {
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex; 
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-direction:column;
  justify-content:space-between;
  /* background-color: cadetblue; */
}
.album-info:first-child {
  flex-grow:1;
}

.album-info h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.album-info h4 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.album-info button {
  background-color: #921233;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
}

.album-info button:hover {
  background-color: #92a113;
}
```

```html
<div class="Track">
  <h1 class="title">Song Playlist</h1>
  <div class="track-list">
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <h4>
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisquam sint dolorum quasi labore dolore inventore voluptatum nostrum adipisci est temporibus iure in, obcaecati neque tenetur tempore nisi sapiente molestias.
            </h4>
          </div>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <h4>
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisquamiente molestias.
            </h4>
           </div>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <div>
            <h2>Title</h2>
            <h4>
              Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisqadipisci est temporibus iure in, obcaecati neque tenetur tempore nisi sapiente molestias.
            </h4>
          </div>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
        <div>
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum do sapiente molestias.
          </h4>
          </div>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
        <div>
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisquam sint dolorum quasi labore dolore inventore voluptatum molestias.
          </h4>
          </div>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this lines to your `.album-info` class:

```css
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  height: 87%;
```

and this line to your `.album-info button` class:

```css
margin-top: auto;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", "Roboto", "Oxygen", "Ubuntu", "Cantarell", "Fira Sans", "Droid Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: #345676;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
}

button {
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.Track {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.title {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.track-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.track-item {
  display: flex;
  width: 25%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.album {
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  width: 15rem;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;  
}

.album-image {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.album-image img {
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.album-info {
  padding: 1rem;
  /* background-color: cadetblue; */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;  
  height: 87%;
}

.album-info h2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.album-info h4 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.album-info button {
  background-color: #921233;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.album-info button:hover {
  background-color: #92a113;
}
```

```html
<div class="Track">
  <h1 class="title">Song Playlist</h1>
  <div class="track-list">
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisquam sint dolorum quasi labore dolore inventore voluptatum nostrum adipisci est temporibus iure in, obcaecati neque tenetur tempore nisi sapiente molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisquamiente molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisqadipisci est temporibus iure in, obcaecati neque tenetur tempore nisi sapiente molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum do sapiente molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="track-item">
      <div class="album">
        <div class="album-image">
          <img src="#" alt="This will be an image" />
        </div>
        <div class="album-info">
          <h2>Title</h2>
          <h4>
            Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptate quisquam sint dolorum quasi labore dolore inventore voluptatum molestias.
          </h4>
          <button>Select</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```